# How can I make it so that the program loops until the conditions are met?

Tags: python, loops

I was trying to make it so that my program will keep asking the user to input a certain value and if the user doesn't it keeps asking until they do.

I tried to use "while" instead of "if" but I know I'm probably missing something, somewhere.

```
def terrain(surface):
    surface = raw_input("What surface will you be driving on? ")
    if surface == "ice":
                u = raw_input("what is the velocity of the car in meters per second? ")
                u = int(u)
                if u < 0:
                    u = raw_input("Velocity must be greater than 0")
                    return
                if u == 0:
                    u = raw_input("Velocty must be a number greater than zero")
                    return
                a = raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
                a = int(a)
                if a > 0:
                    print ("Deceleration cannot be a positive integer")
                    return
                else: 
                        s1 = u**2
                        s2 = 2*.08*9.8
                    s = s1/s2
                    print "This is how far the vehicle will travel on ice: "
                    print ("The vehicle will travel %i meters before coming to a complete stop" % (s))
terrain("ice")
```

Comment: You need to use `while True` then break when the user gives the appropriate input. What did you miss?

Comment: I'd suggest to make some validate function and then do smth like `a = input(); while not validate(a): a = input()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `return` after checking the condition which causes the function to return `None` you have to use `break` instead of `return` with while loop instead of `if` to achieve this. A better way to validate and get data is below

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

def validate_and_get_data_count(x):
    if int(x) < 0:
        raise ValidationError("Cannot be less than 0")
    return int(x)

def validate_and_get_data_name(x):
    if len(x) < 8:
        raise ValidationError("Length of name cannot be less than 8 chars")
    elif len(x) > 10:
        raise ValidationError("Length of name cannot be greater than 10 chars")
    return x

validators = {
    "count": validate_and_get_data_count,
    "name": validate_and_get_data_name
}

data = {}

params = [
    ("count","Please enter a count: "),
    ("name","Please enter a name: "),
]

for param in params:
    while True:
        x = input(param[1])
        try:
            data[param[0]] = validators[param[0]](x)
            break
        except ValidationError as e:
            print(e)

print(data)
```

What the above code does is for every `param` in `params` list it runs a while loop checking for every validation condition defined in its validator if valid it breaks the while loop and proceeds to next `param` and repeats the same process again